I tried overwriting an element with a confirmation notification, I tried to remove this notification on confirmation but it returns 'NaN'
I created a div element with two buttons in it:
<div class="js-button-container">
      <button class="reset-score-btn js-reset-score-btn">Reset   `indent`Score</button>
      <button>Auto Play</button>
</div>

The reset button is to bring up a notification asking if the user is sure of resetting the score and on confirmation, it should clear off.
the bug now is that it completely clears all the contents in the div elements as seen in the image(showing Nan whereas it is supposed to just clear off the confirmation notification only.
this is the js code to generate the html to confirm a reset:
document.querySelector('.js-reset-score-btn').addEventListener('click',             `indent`    () =\> {

    const html = `
      <div>Are you sure you want to reset score?
        <button class="js-yes-btn">Yes</button>
        <button class="js-no-btn">No</button>
      </div>
    `;
    
const buttonContainerElement = document.querySelector('.js-button `indent`    container');
    buttonContainerElement.innerHTML += html;
    
    document.querySelector('.js-yes-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      score.wins = 0;
      score.losses = 0;
      score.ties = 0;
      localStorage.removeItem('score');
      updateScoreElement();
      buttonContainerElement.innerHTML -= html;
      console.log(buttonContainerElement);
    });
    
    document.querySelector('.js-no-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      buttonContainerElement.innerHTML -= html;
      console.log(buttonContainerElement);


Instead of screenshots, please provide the HTML. You can even make the code runnable by inserting a stack snippet (using the toolbar in the editor). But at least, we need the HTML. Secondly, your code does not parse. addEventListener('click', `indent` () =\> { has several syntax issues.

The 'indent' part isn't part of my actual code, let's just say I'm just getting used to the interface. I didn't know I could make my code runnable. I'd try editing it

You can considerably simplify your code and prevent the problems you have using event delegation and a bit of css. Here is a  minimal reproducable example.


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`reset-score-btn`)) {
    return document.querySelector(`.resetDialog`).classList.add(`active`);
  }
  
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`js-yes-btn`)) {
    /* process reset request*/
    document.querySelector(`.resetState`).dataset.reset = `YES`;
    return document.querySelector(`.resetDialog`).classList.remove(`active`);
  }
  
    if (evt.target.classList.contains(`js-no-btn`)) {
    /* do nothing and hide dialog*/
    document.querySelector(`.resetState`).dataset.reset = `NO`;
    return document.querySelector(`.resetDialog`).classList.remove(`active`);
  }
}
.resetDialog {
  display: none;
}

.resetDialog.active {
  display: block;
}

.resetState:after {
  content: ' 'attr(data-reset);
}
<div class="js-button-container">
  <button class="reset-score-btn">Reset `indent`Score</button>
  <button>Auto Play</button>
  <span class="resetState" data-reset="NO">Score reset?</span>
  
  <div class="resetDialog">
    <div>Are you sure?</div>
    <div>
      <button class="js-yes-btn">Yes</button>
      <button class="js-no-btn">No</button>
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>



